# Get dimensions of gif with image magick

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I used to get the dimensions of a jpg image with this command:

```
height=`convert $filename -format '%h' info:` 
width=`convert $filename -format '%w' info:`
```

but if I try this on a gif, I get a list of integer as output:

```
echo "height=$height"
```

height=315
165
236
272
168
168
168
168
168
287
281
287

(the correct height is 315)

How do I get only the value I need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your getting the dimensions of all the frames in the gif. Try accessing the first frame with `filename[frame#]` format.

```
height=`convert $filename[0] -format '%h' info:` 
width=`convert $filename[0] -format '%w' info:`
```